# Finding multiple indexes from source string

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, string

Basically I need to do String.IndexOf() and I need to get array of indexes from the source string.

Is there easy way to get array of indexes?

Before asking this question I have Googled a lot, but have not found easy solution to solve this simple problem.

Comment: Can the instances of the substring overlap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    var indexs = "Prashant".MultipleIndex('a');

//Extension Method's Class
    public static class Extensions
    {
         static int i = 0;

         public static int[] MultipleIndex(this string StringValue, char chChar)
         {

           var indexs = from rgChar in StringValue
                        where rgChar == chChar && i != StringValue.IndexOf(rgChar, i + 1)
                        select new { Index = StringValue.IndexOf(rgChar, i + 1), Increament = (i = i + StringValue.IndexOf(rgChar)) };
            i = 0;
            return indexs.Select(p => p.Index).ToArray<int>();
          }
    }
```

Comment: How would I do it, if I needed  chChar to be string?

Thank You.

Answer (score 16):

How about this extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> IndexesOf(this string haystack, string needle)
{
    int lastIndex = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        int index = haystack.IndexOf(needle, lastIndex);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        yield return index;
        lastIndex = index + needle.Length;
    }
}
```

Note that when looking for "AA" in "XAAAY" this code will now only yield 1.

If you really need an array, call `ToArray()` on the result. (This is assuming .NET 3.5 and hence LINQ support.)

Comment: Could you please adjust it, so that it would return only 1

Comment: instead of advancing by 1, advance by the length of the needle -- to use Jon's nomenclature :)

Comment: Exactly - but it can be slightly tricky to work out exactly where to do that :) I've fixed the code.

Answer (score 6):

You would have to loop, I suspect:

```
        int start = 0;
        string s = "abcdeafghaji";
        int index;
        while ((index = s.IndexOf('a', start)) >= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(index);
            start = index + 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a solution that utilizes regex can be more reliable, using the indexOf function can be unreliable. It will find all matches and indexes, not matching an exact phrase which can lead to unexpected results. This function resolves that by making use of the Regex library.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> IndexesOf(string haystack, string needle)
{
       Regex r = new Regex("\\b(" + needle + ")\\b");
       MatchCollection m = r.Matches(haystack);

       return from Match o in m select o.Index;
}
```