# c# advice about counting word "in" and replacing it with "ter"

Tags: c#

I want that user write what ever string he wish  (one word or whole sentence) and then I want to find each "in" and replace it with "ter" but before replacing it, the position of each "in" should be printed.

```
  Console.Write("Write some string: ");
  string s1 = Console.ReadLine();

  s1 = s1.Replace("in", "ter");
  Console.WriteLine("After replacement we got new string {0}!", s1);
  Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: `IndexOf` is your friend. There is an overload that takes a start index. Use that overload to find all occurrences.

Comment: is this a homework assignment..

Comment: Documentation for IndexOf: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx

Comment: yes it is - I know how to replace it but I did not know how to make them count each "in" before replacing it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx).

```
bool done = false;
int startIndex = 0;
while (!done)
{
    var index = s1.IndexOf("in", startIndex);
    if (index < 0)
    {
        done = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found at position {0}", index);
        startIndex = index + 2;
    }
    if (startIndex >= s1.Length)
    {
        done = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chris Wue - I never used var but even so its working and thanks you big time *hugs*

Comment: Woo it's hugs time up in here

Answer (score 2):

To make ChrisWue's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8810019/347172) more short, here's an updated version:

```
public void DisplayAllIndexes(string text, string search)
{
    //Argument Validation
    if (text == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
    if (search == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("search");

    int index = 0;

    while ((index = text.IndexOf(search, index)) != -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found at position {0}", index);

        index += search.Length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find just a single occurrence of a phrase you can use `IndexOf`. Example:

```
string s = "The word 'in' is in my test sentence two times.";
int index = s.IndexOf("in");
```

That will give you the **first** position of the world "in" (or it will return `-1` if it doesn't find the word).

However, since there may be multiple occurrences of the word you're looking for, you'll have to do something a little more complicated. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767767/finding-multiple-indexes-from-source-string) has a good discussion of ways to find multiple occurrences of a word.