# How to count of sub-string occurrences within a string (not char occurrences)

Tags: c#, string

Suppose I have a string like:

```
MyString = "OU=Level3,OU=Level2,OU=Level1,DC=domain,DC=com";
```

then I want to know how many time of occurrences of sub-string "OU=" in this string. With single char, maybe there is something like:

```
int count = MyString.Split("OU=").Length - 1;
```

but `Split` only works for `char`, not `string`.

Also how to find the position of n occurrences? For example, the position of 2nd `"OU="` in the string?

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: `String.Split` has several overloads that allow you to split by strings.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx

Comment: split does not work only for chars...

Comment: You could have done this using Multiple Delim I would be more than happy to post you a simple coded example for future use. `and Split does work on a string` `Remember that Split() returns an Array so in the case of string it would return string[] you would need to create new string[] { "somestring", "someotherString"..etc..}`

Answer (score 221, accepted):

```
Regex.Matches(input, "OU=").Count
```

Comment: Thank you. Also how to find the position of n occurances? for example, the pos of 2rd time "OU=" in the string?

Comment: Poked around a bit and found this question on SO which should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767767/finding-multiple-indexes-from-source-string

Comment: In generally, what if the subString to match contains regex characters? Regex.Matches(input, Regex.Escape(subString)).Count works for all possible substrings.

Comment: in general is would be wise to use `Regex.Escape(...)`, so abstract version: `Regex.Matches(input, Regex.Escape("string_which_isnt_a_regex")).Count`

Comment: Take the example of string `aaaaaa` and substring `aa`. This answer produces a count of 3 where the real count of substring `aa` is 5.

Answer (score 22):

You can find all the occurrences and their positions with `IndexOf`:

```
string MyString = "OU=Level3,OU=Level2,OU=Level1,DC=domain,DC=com";
string stringToFind = "OU=";

List<int> positions = new List<int>();
int pos = 0;
while ((pos < MyString.Length) && (pos = MyString.IndexOf(stringToFind, pos)) != -1)
{
    positions.Add(pos);
    pos += stringToFind.Length();
}

Console.WriteLine("{0} occurrences", positions.Count);
foreach (var p in positions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

You can get the same result from a regular expression:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(MyString, "OU=");
Console.WriteLine("{0} occurrences", matches.Count);
foreach (var m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Index);
}
```

The primary differences:

- The Regex code is shorter
- The Regex code allocates a collection and multiple strings.
- The IndexOf code could be written to output the position immediately, without creating a collection.
- It's likely that the Regex code will be faster in isolation, but if used many times the combined overhead of the string allocations could cause a much higher load on the garbage collector.

If I were writing this in-line, as something that didn't get used often, I'd probably go with the regex solution. If I were to put it into a library as something to be used a lot, I'd probably go with the IndexOf solution.

Comment: Small typo? List<int> positions = new List<int>[]; should be List<int> positions = new List<int>();

Comment: I believe this is a better solution.  If the string you are trying to match is something like  .s   then the regex will return the incorrect number.  With the while loop that was proposed by Jim counts the number of  .s  correctly.

Answer (score 12):

this extension needs less resources than regualr expressions.

```
public static int CountSubstring(this string text, string value)
{                  
    int count = 0, minIndex = text.IndexOf(value, 0);
    while (minIndex != -1)
    {
        minIndex = text.IndexOf(value, minIndex + value.Length);
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

usage:

```
MyString = "OU=Level3,OU=Level2,OU=Level1,DC=domain,DC=com";
int count = MyString.CountSubstring("OU=");
```

Answer (score 7):

(Clippy-mode:**ON**)

You look like you're parsing an LDAP query!

Would you like to parse it:

- manually? Goto "SplittingAndParsing"
- Automagically via Win32 calls? Goto "Using Win32 via PInvoke"

(Clippy-mode:**OFF**)

**"SplittingAndParsing":**

```
var MyString = "OU=Level3,OU=Level2,OU=Level1,DC=domain,DC=com";
var chunksAsKvps = MyString
    .Split(',')
    .Select(chunk => 
        { 
            var bits = chunk.Split('='); 
            return new KeyValuePair<string,string>(bits[0], bits[1]);
        });

var allOUs = chunksAsKvps
    .Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals("OU", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

**"Using Win32 via PInvoke":**

Usage:

```
var parsedDn = Win32LDAP.ParseDN(str);    
var allOUs2 = parsedDn
    .Where(dn => dn.Key.Equals("OU", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Utility Code:

```
// I don't remember where I got this from, honestly...I *think* it came
// from another SO user long ago, but those details I've lost to history...
public class Win32LDAP
{
   #region Constants
   public const int ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;
   public const int ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW = 111;
   #endregion Constants

   #region DN Parsing
   [DllImport("ntdsapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
   protected static extern int DsGetRdnW(
       ref IntPtr ppDN, 
       ref int pcDN, 
       out IntPtr ppKey, 
       out int pcKey, 
       out IntPtr ppVal, 
       out int pcVal
   );

   public static KeyValuePair<string, string> GetName(string distinguishedName)
   {
       IntPtr pDistinguishedName = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(distinguishedName);
       try
       {
           IntPtr pDN = pDistinguishedName, pKey, pVal;
           int cDN = distinguishedName.Length, cKey, cVal;

           int lastError = DsGetRdnW(ref pDN, ref cDN, out pKey, out cKey, out pVal, out cVal);

           if(lastError == ERROR_SUCCESS)
           {
               string key, value;

               if(cKey < 1)
               {
                   key = string.Empty;
               }
               else
               {
                   key = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pKey, cKey);
               }

               if(cVal < 1)
               {
                   value = string.Empty;
               }
               else
               {
                   value = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pVal, cVal);
               }

               return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value);
           }
           else
           {
               throw new Win32Exception(lastError);
           }
       }
       finally
       {
           Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pDistinguishedName);
       }
   }

   public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ParseDN(string distinguishedName)
   {
       List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> components = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
       IntPtr pDistinguishedName = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(distinguishedName);
       try
       {
           IntPtr pDN = pDistinguishedName, pKey, pVal;
           int cDN = distinguishedName.Length, cKey, cVal;

           do
           {
               int lastError = DsGetRdnW(ref pDN, ref cDN, out pKey, out cKey, out pVal, out cVal);

               if(lastError == ERROR_SUCCESS)
               {
                   string key, value;

                   if(cKey < 0)
                   {
                       key = null;
                   }
                   else if(cKey == 0)
                   {
                       key = string.Empty;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       key = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pKey, cKey);
                   }

                   if(cVal < 0)
                   {
                       value = null;
                   }
                   else if(cVal == 0)
                   {
                       value = string.Empty;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       value = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pVal, cVal);
                   }

                   components.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value));

                   pDN = (IntPtr)(pDN.ToInt64() + UnicodeEncoding.CharSize); //skip over comma
                   cDN--;
               }
               else
               {
                   throw new Win32Exception(lastError);
               }
           } while(cDN > 0);

           return components;
       }
       finally
       {
           Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pDistinguishedName);
       }
   }

   [DllImport("ntdsapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
   protected static extern int DsQuoteRdnValueW(
       int cUnquotedRdnValueLength,
       string psUnquotedRdnValue,
       ref int pcQuotedRdnValueLength,
       IntPtr psQuotedRdnValue
   );

   public static string QuoteRDN(string rdn)
   {
       if (rdn == null) return null;

       int initialLength = rdn.Length;
       int quotedLength = 0;
       IntPtr pQuotedRDN = IntPtr.Zero;

       int lastError = DsQuoteRdnValueW(initialLength, rdn, ref quotedLength, pQuotedRDN);

       switch (lastError)
       {
           case ERROR_SUCCESS:
               {
                   return string.Empty;
               }
           case ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
               {
                   break; //continue
               }
           default:
               {
                   throw new Win32Exception(lastError);
               }
       }

       pQuotedRDN = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(quotedLength * UnicodeEncoding.CharSize);

       try
       {
           lastError = DsQuoteRdnValueW(initialLength, rdn, ref quotedLength, pQuotedRDN);

           switch(lastError)
           {
               case ERROR_SUCCESS:
                   {
                       return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pQuotedRDN, quotedLength);
                   }
               default:
                   {
                       throw new Win32Exception(lastError);
                   }
           }
       }
       finally
       {
           if(pQuotedRDN != IntPtr.Zero)
           {
               Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pQuotedRDN);
           }
       }
   }


   [DllImport("ntdsapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
   protected static extern int DsUnquoteRdnValueW(
       int cQuotedRdnValueLength,
       string psQuotedRdnValue,
       ref int pcUnquotedRdnValueLength,
       IntPtr psUnquotedRdnValue
   );

   public static string UnquoteRDN(string rdn)
   {
       if (rdn == null) return null;

       int initialLength = rdn.Length;
       int unquotedLength = 0;
       IntPtr pUnquotedRDN = IntPtr.Zero;

       int lastError = DsUnquoteRdnValueW(initialLength, rdn, ref unquotedLength, pUnquotedRDN);

       switch (lastError)
       {
           case ERROR_SUCCESS:
               {
                   return string.Empty;
               }
           case ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
               {
                   break; //continue
               }
           default:
               {
                   throw new Win32Exception(lastError);
               }
       }

       pUnquotedRDN = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(unquotedLength * UnicodeEncoding.CharSize);

       try
       {
           lastError = DsUnquoteRdnValueW(initialLength, rdn, ref unquotedLength, pUnquotedRDN);

           switch(lastError)
           {
               case ERROR_SUCCESS:
                   {
                       return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pUnquotedRDN, unquotedLength);
                   }
               default:
                   {
                       throw new Win32Exception(lastError);
                   }
           }
       }
       finally
       {
           if(pUnquotedRDN != IntPtr.Zero)
           {
               Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pUnquotedRDN);
           }
       }
   }
   #endregion DN Parsing
}

public class DNComponent
{
   public string Type { get; protected set; }
   public string EscapedValue { get; protected set; }
   public string UnescapedValue { get; protected set; }
   public string WholeComponent { get; protected set; }

   public DNComponent(string component, bool isEscaped)
   {
       string[] tokens = component.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);
       setup(tokens[0], tokens[1], isEscaped);
   }

   public DNComponent(string key, string value, bool isEscaped)
   {
       setup(key, value, isEscaped);
   }

   private void setup(string key, string value, bool isEscaped)
   {
       Type = key;

       if(isEscaped)
       {
           EscapedValue = value;
           UnescapedValue = Win32LDAP.UnquoteRDN(value);
       }
       else
       {
           EscapedValue = Win32LDAP.QuoteRDN(value);
           UnescapedValue = value;
       }

       WholeComponent = Type + "=" + EscapedValue;
   }

   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
       if (obj is DNComponent)
       {
           DNComponent dnObj = (DNComponent)obj;
           return dnObj.WholeComponent.Equals(this.WholeComponent, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
       }
       return base.Equals(obj);
   }

   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
       return WholeComponent.GetHashCode();
   }
}

public class DistinguishedName
{
   public DNComponent[] Components
   {
       get
       {
           return components.ToArray();
       }
   }

   private List<DNComponent> components;
   private string cachedDN;

   public DistinguishedName(string distinguishedName)
   {
       cachedDN = distinguishedName;
       components = new List<DNComponent>();
       foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in Win32LDAP.ParseDN(distinguishedName))
       {
           components.Add(new DNComponent(kvp.Key, kvp.Value, true));
       }
   }

   public DistinguishedName(IEnumerable<DNComponent> dnComponents)
   {
       components = new List<DNComponent>(dnComponents);
       cachedDN = GetWholePath(",");
   }

   public bool Contains(DNComponent dnComponent)
   {
       return components.Contains(dnComponent);
   }

   public string GetDNSDomainName()
   {
       List<string> dcs = new List<string>();
       foreach (DNComponent dnc in components)
       {
           if(dnc.Type.Equals("DC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
           {
               dcs.Add(dnc.UnescapedValue);
           }
       }
       return string.Join(".", dcs.ToArray());
   }

   public string GetDomainDN()
   {
       List<string> dcs = new List<string>();
       foreach (DNComponent dnc in components)
       {
           if(dnc.Type.Equals("DC", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
           {
               dcs.Add(dnc.WholeComponent);
           }
       }
       return string.Join(",", dcs.ToArray());
   }

   public string GetWholePath()
   {
       return GetWholePath(",");
   }

   public string GetWholePath(string separator)
   {
       List<string> parts = new List<string>();
       foreach (DNComponent component in components)
       {
           parts.Add(component.WholeComponent);
       }
       return string.Join(separator, parts.ToArray());
   }

   public DistinguishedName GetParent()
   {
       if(components.Count == 1)
       {
           return null;
       }
       List<DNComponent> tempList = new List<DNComponent>(components);
       tempList.RemoveAt(0);
       return new DistinguishedName(tempList);
   }

   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
       if(obj is DistinguishedName)
       {
           DistinguishedName objDN = (DistinguishedName)obj;
           if (this.Components.Length == objDN.Components.Length)
           {
               for (int i = 0; i < this.Components.Length; i++)
               {
                   if (!this.Components[i].Equals(objDN.Components[i]))
                   {
                       return false;
                   }
               }
               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
       return base.Equals(obj);
   }

   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
       return cachedDN.GetHashCode();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

below should work

```
  MyString = "OU=Level3,OU=Level2,OU=Level1,DC=domain,DC=com";
  int count = Regex.Matches(MyString, "OU=").Count
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int count = myString.Split(new []{','})
                    .Count(item => item.StartsWith(
                        "OU=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: Not to toot my own horn, but this is reliant on there being comma separation. Sure, it works in this very specific scenario, but my Regex solution is simpler and more dynamic.

Comment: Yes, I agree, just giving an alternative.

Comment: Absolutely, I can appreciate that. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here are two examples of how you can get the results that you are looking for

```
var MyString = "OU=Level3,OU=Level2,OU=Level1,DC=domain,DC=com";
```

This one you would see a list of the values separated but it would have DC just an idea to 
show that the split with String does work`

```
var split = MyString.Split(new string[] { "OU=", "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This one will Split and return you only the 3 items into a List so that if you don't rely on a count you can visually validate that it returns the 3 Levels of `OU=``

```
var lstSplit = MyString.Split(new[] { ',' })
        .Where(splitItem => splitItem.StartsWith(
               "OU=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int CountOccurences(string needle, string haystack)
{
    return (haystack.Length - haystack.Replace(needle, "").Length) / needle.Length;
}
```

Benchmarked it against other answers here (the regex one and the "IndexOf" one), works faster.

Comment: that's just a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string add at least a reference