# find Count of Substring in string C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, count, substring, indexof

I am trying to find how many times the word "Serotonin" appears in the gathered web data but cannot find a method for finding the number of times.

```
IEnumerator OnMouseDown()
{


    string GatheredData;
    StringToFind = "Serotonin"

    string url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine";

    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    GatheredData = www.text;


    //Attempted methods below

    M1_count = GatheredData.Contains(StringToFind);

    M1_count = GatheredData.Count(StringToFind);

    M1_count = GatheredData.IndexOf(StringToFind);



}
```

I can easily use the data from those methods 1 and 3 when I tell it what number in the index and method 2 would work but only works for chars not strings

I have checked online and on here but found nothing of finding the count of the StringToFind

Comment: GatheredData.IndexOf(string/char StringToFind,int starindex,int count);

Comment: oh true, the displacement method... that would work yes if no built in way

Comment: Preferring index of, how do I know how many other than indexof-ing until null? Or would that be the method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count of sub-string occurrences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577464/how-to-count-of-sub-string-occurrences)

Comment: Depending on how many times you think the string "as" occurs in the string "aaaaaa" (I can imagine answers of 3 and 5), you may want to do things one way or another.

Comment: Oops, autocorrect strikes again. Doing this on a phone on a Sunday evening can be a bad idea. That's "aa" into "aaaaaa". Boy, it's hard to fight off autocorrect sometimes. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you count occurrences of a string (actually a char) within a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-actually-a-char-within-a-string)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assume string is like this

```
string test = "word means collection of chars, and every word has meaning";
```

then just use regex to find how many times word is matched in your `test` string like this

```
int count = Regex.Matches(test, "word").Count;
```

output would be `2`

Comment: I just tried your method, it works perfect, thank you!

Comment: Use: `Regex.Escape(str)` to ensure it can handle all inputs

Comment: Is not working for case :
string test = "examplecom.com"
int count = Regex.Matches(test, ".com").Count;
It will get 2 instide 1

Answer (score 1):

The solution
`int count = Regex.Matches(someString, potencialSubstring).Count;`

did not work for me. Even thou I used `Regex.Escape(str)`

So I wrote it myself, it is quite slow, but the performance is not an issue in my app.

```
private static List<int> StringOccurencesCount(String haystack, String needle, StringComparison strComp)
{
  var results = new List<int>();
  int index = haystack.IndexOf(needle, strComp);
  while (index != -1)
  {
    results.Add(index);
    index = haystack.IndexOf(needle, index + needle.Length, strComp);
  }
  return results;
}
```

Maybe someone will find this useful.

Comment: Congratulations, you have just invented the square wheel ;-)  
The regex solution works but "potencialSubstring" is a regex pattern.  `Matches (string input, string pattern);` and `Regex.Escape` does not escape every possible char.
If you want an alternative why not using `string.Split`, then you don't need escape your potencialSubstring.

Answer (score 0):

Improvement on @Petr Nohejl's excellent answer:

```cs
public static int Count (this string s, string substr, StringComparison strComp = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
{
    int count = 0, index = s.IndexOf(substr, strComp);
    while (index != -1)
    {
        count++;
        index = s.IndexOf(substr, index + substr.Length, strComp);
    }
    return count;
}
```

This does not use `Regex.Matches` and probably has better performance and is more predictable.

[See on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JxOiuY)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't worry about performance, here are 3 alternative solutions:

```
int Count(string src, string target)
    => src.Length - src.Replace(target, target[1..]).Length;
```

---

```
int Count(string src, string target)
    => src.Split(target).Length - 1;
```

---

```
int Count(string src, string target)
    => Enumerable
        .Range(0, src.Length - target.Length + 1)
        .Count(index => src.Substring(index, target.Length) == target);
```

Answer (score -1):

Oh yes, I have it now.

I will split() the array and get the length

2nd to that I will IndexOf until I return a -1

Thanks for help in the comments!

Comment: That'll work, but the regex solution above is far more simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution would be to use Regex:

```
var count = Regex.Matches(GatheredData.ToLower(), String.Format("\b{0}\b", StringToFind)).Count;
```

Comment: You probably want to use `Regex.Escape(StringToFind)` instead. It's also probably worth mentioning that `\b` expects a boundary, so `SerotoninSerotonin` won't be matched, but `Serotonin Serotonin` will be. In the context of what OP wants, I think that's OK though :)

Comment: Exactly, my answer IS for what he exactly needs :) but thanks John!