# Why Regex Count works as Length in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string, count, substring

I was looking for an answer for "how to count the occurrence of a substring in the desired string in c# using Regex?". There are many references like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577464/how-to-count-of-sub-string-occurrences) to use "Count" as following:

```
int count = Regex.Match(MyString, "OU=").Count
```

I tried to use it but every time in c# there was an error message and a suggestion to use ".Length".

Eventually, I did it using the following code snippet.

```
    private int GetCounts(string source, string substring)
    {
        int iCount = 0;
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(source, substring))
            iCount++;
        return iCount;
    }
```

Could anybody explain why ".Count" is not working as expected?
Answers appreciated in advance.

Comment: Please provide the error message

Comment: Hi. Welcome to [so]. Help us help you. Can you please provide at least a sample test, tell how it does not match your requirements. Ideally provide a [mcve].

Comment: are you using a framework version below 4.8 ? Because this property exists and I can compile your first line of code without problems. Here is [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.count?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @MongZhu `MatchCollection.Count` has been available since 1.1

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ywGttu

Comment: @canton7 haha thank you, I was looking at the wrong place for the version. stupid :D

Comment: Please show your RegEx and the string leading to the error. The only reason why `.Count` would fail (that is, with a `RegexMatchTimeoutException`) is when the RegEx evaluation takes to long, indicating an incorrect RegEx.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow He said "*I tried to use it but every time in c# there was an error message and a suggestion to use ".Length".*", indicating that it's not a problem with a timeout, but instead it's a compile-time error. Also he did show us his Regex string: `"OU="`

Comment: @canton7 Yes. Exactly. More interestingly somebody voted down the question when you guys are trying to help. Thanks to all you, guys.:-)

Comment: @amirfg It's being downvoted because we cannot reproduce it. The code you gave us does not cause the error you say it causes. That makes it a bad question.

Comment: I took the liberty and changed the code to make the problem reproducible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely used [`Regex.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Match_System_String_System_String_) when you should have used [`Regex.Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Matches_System_String_System_String_).

The first returns a [`Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match?view=netframework-4.8), which only has a [`Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.length?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Capture_Length) property, while the latter returns a [`MatchCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection?view=netframework-4.8) only having a [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.count?view=netframework-4.8) property.

Comment: (@amirfg This is why it's important that your question is correct. Please always make sure that the code in your question is actually the code you're trying to run)