# Assert a string contains a substring X times - XUnit (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, testing, xunit

I couldn't find any example for XUnit, although I know JUnit and Moq have this option.

I have a string that contains 3 times the same substring, or should, and I want to assert that. I am using XUnit but I cannot find any way of asserting this in a clean way, using something that the library offers.

Is there any out-of-the-box option for this?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a common requirement to me, so I'd be surprised to find it exists out of the both.

Comment: Actually I just realized a regex should do it. But I'll leave the question open, I think it can be useful for someone looking for the same thing.

Comment: I'm curious, how would you do that in JUnit and Moq?

Comment: Not out of the box, but you can [count the substring occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577464/how-to-count-of-sub-string-occurrences).

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose I would define extension method that would do correct assertion:

```
public static class TestUtils
{
    public static void AssertContainsXTimes(this string actual, string expectedSubstring, int times)
    {
        var actualRemovedLength = actual.Length - actual.Replace(expectedSubstring, string.Empty).Length;
        var expectedRemovedLength = expectedSubstring.Length * times;

        Assert.Equal(expectedRemovedLength, actualRemovedLength);
    }

    public static void AssertContainsAtLeastXTimes(this string actual, string expectedSubstring, int times)
    {
        var actualRemovedLength = actual.Length - actual.Replace(expectedSubstring, string.Empty).Length;
        var expectedRemovedLength = expectedSubstring.Length * times;

        Assert.True(actualRemovedLength >= expectedRemovedLength);
    }
}
```

And below is the screenshot of sample unit tests with their result for better understanding:
[image]

Comment: This is dirty though, as it leaves a garbage string after replacing. Also, does "eeee" contain "ee" twice or thrice?

Comment: @CodeCaster IMO matches should not overlap, i disagree that it's dirty ? In what way? But let's see if OP will find my answer useful

Comment: "as it leaves a garbage string after replacing"

Comment: @CodeCaster well , i can read :) i meant that it's totally unclear what you have meant by that

Comment: `string.Replace()` returns a new string after replacing, if something was replaced. This increases memory usage. It generates a garbage string for the garbage collector to collect. It is a wasteful implementation of a substring count.